# Connect Visual Studio 2008 to Virtual PC 2007

Tags: visual-studio

How do I go about connecting Visual Studio on my host machine to Window Server 2008 that is running in VPC? I basically want to be able to deploy ASP.Net apps to it as well as access the apps from the host machines browser.

Answer (score 2):

Treat the VPC in exactly the same way as if it were a separate physical machine.

VS and the browser on the host will simply use HTTP to communicate to the IIS/ASP.NET instance on the VPC guest.